# Using the node.js google cloud speech to text, how can I get the status of a current job?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-speech

I managed to trigger a job with:

```
        const config = {
            languageCode: 'en-US',
            enableSpeakerDiarization: true,
            audioChannelCount: 2,
            enableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel: true,
            useEnhanced: true,
            profanityFilter: false,
            enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
        };

        const audio = {
            uri: `gs://${filePath}`
        }

        const requestObj = {
            config: config,
            audio: audio
        }
        return speechClient.longRunningRecognize(requestObj)
```

I get back an object with a `name`. I want to use that with https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/LongRunningRecognizeMetadata (via the node.js package) to get the current status.

How do I do it?

```
return speechClient.longrunning.Operation()
```

Seems not to exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can do it with:

```
                return speechClient.operationsClient.getOperation({ name: googleName })
```

This is not super well documented

Comment: fyr https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.longrunning#google.longrunning.Operations.GetOperation https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/speech/latest/google.longrunning.html https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/speech/latest/v1.SpeechClient.html#longRunningRecognize